# Creating and Exploring Media Files placed in multiple network computers

Tags: c#, php, networking, network-programming

A friend of mine has an Internet cafe, and he wants to put the media files (Movies, Series etc) on all network computers so he can use the free space in each computer drive (400GB in each PC). So he wants me to design an application that controls all media files from a server (Deleting - Copying - Updating) + a web interface to allow clients exploring them.
My first question how can i view media files on the network computers using php?

Comment: Yes, an idea, start writting a server and a client.

Comment: yep buddy i have that in mind. but wouldn't the app crash when transferring hundreds of large files, plus how can i view the media files using php? am kinda making a feasibility study.

Comment: If you're thinking if it's possible to do, then you still lack the knowledge to implement it. It can be done, but it's not an easy matter.

Comment: yeah that's why am asking, maybe i didn't ask the right question the first place. let me try again by editing my question

Comment: Don't try to correct it, it will be closed as well, StackOverflow is only for concrete questions about programming, your question is too open and doesn't has an explicit solution.